# jQuery mouseenter only works on first page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code presents a grid of colored cells that change color on mouseenter, leaving a trail of cells of the new color. A button reloads the grid with cells of the original color. Problem is the mouseenter color change works only after the first grid load (on page refresh) but not on subsequent loads after the Create New Grid button is clicked.

I am new to javascript and jQuery and though I've been over the class materials and read some articles on how to do various parts of this, I cannot see what is wrong.

Visit the [jsfiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/terrymorgan/spdt1cge/)

```
var gridWidth = 600;
var fillGrid = function(){
    $('.grid').empty();
  var cellsPer = prompt('How many cells would you like in a side?');
  console.log('cellsPer = ' + cellsPer);
  var cellWidth = (gridWidth / cellsPer) - 1;
    console.log('cellSize = ' + cellWidth);

  var cell = "<div class='cell'></div>";
  for (var i = 0; i < cellsPer**2; i++) {
    $('.grid').append(cell);
  };
  $('.cell').css({
    'background':'blue','height': cellWidth+'px',  'width': cellWidth+'px',
    'float':'left','margin': '0 1px 1px 0'
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  fillGrid();

  $('.grid').css({'width': gridWidth+'px'});

  $('button').click(function(){
        fillGrid();
    });

  $('.cell').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css('background','pink');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move it outside `$(document).ready` function and add the mouse enter functionality as

```
' $(document).on('mouseenter','.cell',function() {
   $(this).css('background','pink');
  });'
```

Answer (score 3):

You where adding the `mouseenter` event listener only once on `$(document).ready`.
When `fillGrid()` gets called, a new set of `'.cell'` elements not bound to the `mouseenter` event get added to DOM.

You must tell them to behave the same again.

See the following snipped:

```js
var gridWidth = 600;
var fillGrid = function(){
 $('.grid').empty();
  var cellsPer = prompt('How many cells would you like in a side?');
  console.log('cellsPer = ' + cellsPer);
  var cellWidth = (gridWidth / cellsPer) - 1;
 console.log('cellSize = ' + cellWidth);

  var cell = "<div class='cell'></div>";
  for (var i = 0; i < cellsPer**2; i++) {
    $('.grid').append(cell);
  };
  $('.cell').css({
   'background':'blue','height': cellWidth+'px',  'width': cellWidth+'px',
    'float':'left','margin': '0 1px 1px 0'
  });
  
  $('.cell').mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).css('background','pink');
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
 fillGrid();

 $('.grid').css({'width': gridWidth+'px'});

  $('button').click(function(){
  fillGrid();
 });
});
```

```css
button{
  display:block;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Create New Grid</button>
  <div class="grid"></div>
```

Comment: Or just delegate handling to the parent, which is more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues I notice with this code
1) `cellsPer ** 2` is not valid. Use `Math.pow` or `cellsPer * cellsPer`
2) You are only setting up the mouse enter listener on document.ready. Calling `empty` on your grid will remove all child elements - attached event listeners and all. This means you will need to re-add the event listeners every time you re-initialize the grid.

Here is an updated snippet with minimal changes to get your code working:

```js
var gridWidth = 600;
var fillGrid = function(){
  $('.grid').empty();
  var cellsPer = prompt('How many cells would you like in a side?');
  console.log('cellsPer = ' + cellsPer);
  var cellWidth = (gridWidth / cellsPer) - 1;
  console.log('cellSize = ' + cellWidth);

  var cell = "<div class='cell'></div>";
  for (var i = 0; i < cellsPer * cellsPer; i++) {
    $('.grid').append(cell);
  };
  $('.cell').css({
   'background':'blue','height': cellWidth+'px',  'width': cellWidth+'px',
    'float':'left','margin': '0 1px 1px 0'
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  fillGrid();

  $('.grid').css({'width': gridWidth+'px'});

  $('button').click(function(){
    fillGrid();
    $('.cell').mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).css('background','pink');
    });
  });
  
  $('.cell').mouseenter(function() {  
    $(this).css('background','pink');
  });
});
```

```css
button{
  display:block;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Create New Grid</button>
<div class="grid"></div>
```

Since you're doing this for a class I'm not going to refactor the code but, one other suggestion I would make is adding the event listener in the `fillGrid` function, that way you neatly encapsulate everything that has to do with the grid in one place.